# How to get modified text from input JQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input

I'm having a problem getting modified text from input. The input is loaded with some text I get from a database and with an option i should take the onlyread attr off and change the values. Thats ok but when i click on the save button after writing something else in the inputs, it gets the old values with .val(). How can i get the new ones?

The code is something like this.

```
    var anInput = $("#anInput").val(); //gets old value
    var otherInput = $("#otherInput").val(); //gets old value
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "html",
          success: doSomething,
          timeout: 4000,
          error: someProblems,
          url: "modules/mod.php",
          data: {anInput: anInput, otherInput: otherInput}
    });
```

I added the AJAX code just to mention that i need the values to do something. AJAX is working.

I know this can be done with a form but that will reload the page and I don't want that.

Sorry for my rusty English and thanks :)

EDIT: Perhaps I'm not correctly speaking when saying "change the values" what I'm doing is selecting the text and writing something else.

I show some information with the inputs, click a button that allows me to modify, type some new text in the inputs and then click "save"

HTML is genereted by another AJAX

```
<div class="infoVideo">
   <input id="anInput" value="someTextFromDataBase">
   <input id="otherInput" value="someTextFromDataBase">
   <input type="button" id="btnMod">
   <input type="button" id="btnSave">
</div>
```

If I erase and type something else in the input .val() is getting old someTextFromDataBase

Comment: Can you show an example where this happens? A jsfiddle perhaps.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "with an option I should take the `onlyread` attr off and change the values"? We need to see how you set the new values so we can figure out why `.val()` isn't picking up the new values correctly.

Comment: I show some information with the inputs, click a button that allows me to modify, type some new text in the inputs and then click "save"

Comment: FYI, it is NOT the policy here at StackOverflow to edit your post with the Solution.  You should use the green checkmark to indicate the answer that provided the solution.  Per our discussion in comments, I have edited my answer to include the actual solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: As per a guess in my comments, there was more than one `#anInput` in the page so the code was only retrieving the value from the first one which was not the one being edited.  The solution is to not have any duplicate id values in the HTML of the page.

---

I suspect that your code isn't really like you show.  You are probably doing these:

```
var anInput = $("#anInput").val(); //gets old value
var otherInput = $("#otherInput").val(); //gets old value
```

only once and then trying to use `anInput` and `otherInput` much later when the form fields have already changed.  You can get the current values by not caching those and just retrieving the current values when you need them by changing this:

```
data: {anInput: anInput, otherInput: otherInput}
```

to this:

```
data: {anInput: $("#anInput").val(), otherInput: $("#otherInput").val()}
```

That way, you are always retrieving the latest and greatest values right before your Ajax call.

Comment: Actually it is like I'm showing. I tried that but it is the same. I'm changing the text in the input by just writing over the old text

Comment: @nicomv95 - Then, the values are not actually changing in the inputs.  Show us the HTML and the code you're using for changing them.  There's likely something wrong in that.

Comment: I added the html code. I'm changing it by hand with my keyboard but that is not updating the value

Comment: @nicomv95 - it seems to work just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pxsmqpL2/ so there's obviously something else going on that you aren't showing us either with your HTML or your JS.

Comment: @nicomv95 - any chance you have more than one of these `#anInput` fields in your page?  If so, the jQuery will likely fetch the value of the first one.

Comment: That was it! I had two inputs with the same id. Thank you so much

Comment: @nicomv95 - OK, glad you got that sorted.  There should NEVER be duplicate IDs anywhere in a page.  Dups lead to very confusing bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm format of data returned by mod.php. The AJAX block is expecting to receive HTML formatted text `dataType: 'html',`  -- but you are sending json, so is that what you are expecting back?

If this note doesn't reveal the solution, then please show us your `doSomething` function - that's where the returned data is handled.

---

Probably you've tried this already, but what happens if you do this:

```
var anInput = $("#anInput").val(); //gets old value
alert(anInput);
var otherInput = $("#otherInput").val(); //gets old value
alert(otherInput);

$.ajax({ //etc });
```

Comment: AJAX is not the problem. The problem is before it gets there, on the two lines before. I inspect element and the variables anInput and otherInput have wrong info.
.val() is saving the html info in the variables but i want the info I wrote in the input

Comment: It shows me the old info. What I think is wrong is that typing the new text directly in the input doesn't change value. How can I get what I typed in the input?

Comment: There is no better way. If you are using `var myVar = $('#elementID').val();` then you ***will*** get the current contents of that element.  Something else is going on. http://jsfiddle.net/8779nnvo/